# How does Azure override a MySQL connection string in a php application?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, azure, azure-sql-database

I know that Azure uses some runtime magic to override the connection string for my .NET applications. However, I'm trying to port over a wordpress blog and it appears the connection information is stored in a file called wp-config.php. If I input the proper values for the blog into that file then all works fine, but I want to deploy from a public github repository. How do I exclude the connection info from wp-config.php and allow azure to override it at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your repository is private you will need to store the wp-config.php file on your Windows Azure instance (or upload it after the fact somehow). Then when the files are pulled into that directory from Github the wp-config.php (assuming no wp-config.php file is in the repo) file will already exist with the connection details.

If you have a private Github repository then it is probably safe to leave the wp-config.php file and values in the repository itself, as only users you give access to the repo can see it.

Comment: That's what I've done for now. So is there no way to get the value from the azure portal?

Comment: You can set values in the "app settings" for a website (Look at the CONFIGURE tab for your site in the portal). You could set a variable there with the connection string value, and that variable is available to your application. This article might shed more light: http://blog.syntaxc4.net/post/2012/07/26/accessing-app-settings-configured-in-windows-azure-web-sites-using-php-and-node-js.aspx

Comment: @BrianSwan 's comment I think should actually be an answer. He wrote 2 good blog posts about this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/10/23/getting-database-connection-information-in-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/09/26/store-db-connection-info-in-windows-azure-web-sites-app-settings.aspx